# Import a python file into another python file on pythonanywhere

Tags: pythonanywhere

I am trying to built a web app on pythonanywhere.

I have a file abc.py and another file xyz.py . In the file xyz.py I want to use a function of abc.py so how do I import abc.py into xyz.py given that they are in the same directory. What will be the import statement? I was trying:

import "absolute/path/to/the/file.py" which didnt work.

Also did

from . import abc.py in xyz.py which also didnt work

Answer (score 1):

PythonAnywhere dev here: if they're in the same directory, then you need to use

```
from abc import functionname
```

[This part of the official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) explains how import works.